# I want to create a QR code. When scanning, the information is sorted down

Tags: javascript, php, html, qr-code, zebra-printers

this my code

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function generateBarCode()
        {
            var nric = $('#text').val();
            var url = 'https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=' + nric + '&amp;size=50x50';
            $('#barcode').attr('src', url);
        }
    </script>
    <style>
        @media print {
            #a , #carton , #text {
                display: none;
            }
        }
        #barcode {
            white-space: pre-wrap;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <b id="a">Carton</b>
    <input type="text" id="carton" name="carton">
    <br>
    <br>
    <textarea id="text" type="text" 
              value="" style="Width:20%"
              oninput='generateBarCode();' autofocus rows="4" cols="20"></textarea>
    <br>

    <img id='barcode' 
         src="https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=HelloWorld&amp;size=100x100" 
         alt="" 
         title="HELLO" 
         width="94" 
         height="94" >
</body>
```

I want to create a QR code. When scanning, the information is sorted down Same as program zebra designer. when i input data in text area like this.
AAA
BBB
CCC
When scanning the QR code, will get the following information.
AAABBBCCC
I want to scan QR code, then display the information like this.
AAA
BBB
CCC
Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Look at the request going out to the API, the line returns are removed, because they are not URL-compatible. You need to encode the value before putting it in the URL: `url = '...' + encodeURIComponent(nric) + '...'`. Then, line breaks will work. Note: some QR code reader apps transform line breaks into simple whitespace. You can't do anything about that, other than using another app

Comment: Not sure URL encoding will do the trick here - it depends on whether line breaks are supported to begin with. What characters you _can_ put in there, depends on the Input Mode, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code#Storage From the documentation of the API you are using there, I can’t tell if they are giving you a choice in that matter.

Comment: @CBroe I tested it with this API (by editing the snippet above), and it worked. Android app "QR Scanner" reads them as whitespace _(trying to replace `\n` with `\r\n` didn't seem to have an impact)_, but the "QR Code Reader" app treated them correctly, so the input mode should be OK